# Reading line delimited text file of strings into a vector of strings in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a text file test.txt like so:

```
a
b
c
```

I want to read them into a matlab 3x1 vector X for example, so that when I type X, it will print:

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

How can I achieve this? I tried importdata and it didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fid = fopen('test.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);
X = C{1};
```

When you type X:

```
X = 

'a'
'b'
'c'
```